# Is random sampling considered a random experiment?

Tags: sampling, inference

A random experiment is defined as "An experiment, trial, or observation that can be repeated numerous times under the same conditions." I was wondering if randomly sampling a part of your dataset is considered a random experiment? Say you have 3000 rows of data and you randomly sample 300 rows to make 
inferences on the data. Is this considered a random experiment? Or how data is collected is considered random experiment? Say you say you record heights of kids of age 9 and their parent's heights.

Comment: The original 3000 are not at all random? Only the selection of the 300?

Comment: @innisfree consider original 3000 as all the responses recorded but it is random if we consider they can't record every individual for the subject the original 3000 is random as well.

Comment: How would this differ from randomly drawing balls from the urn during lottery? Also, why does it matter to you? Why do you ask?

Comment: @Tim I am confused on the definition of random experiment or rather how to interpret it. If I rephrase the question would random experiment be to draw random samples from my dataset or would it be considered as how the dataset is created by asking many kids and their parent's heights many times for different families?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *random experiment* is an experiment or a process for which the outcome cannot be predicted with certainty (e.g. http://aix1.uottawa.ca/~glamothe/mat2377/ProbabilityI.pdf).

In statistical inference a *random sample* is a random variable    $X_1,\dots,X_n$ if $X_1,\dots,X_n$ are independent and identically    distributed random variables (e.g. Casella and Berger, *Statistical    Inference*, Duxbury, 2002).

In the statistical theory of design of experiments, *randomized    experiments* (NB: *randomized*, not *random*) involve randomly allocating the experimental units across    the treatment groups (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_experiment); then the measures of response can be assumed to be the observed values of independent and identically distributed random variables (e.g. Cox and Reid, *The Theory of the Design of Experiments*, Chapman & Hall/CRC, 2000).

According to the *repeated sampling principle*, statistical procedured are to be assessed by their behavior in hypothetical repetition under the same conditions (e.g. Geisser, *Modes of Parametric Statistical Inference*, Wiley Interscience, 2006). If you can randomly extract 3000 experimental units, then other 3000 units under the same conditions, and so on, this is repeated sampling.

Repeated extraction (*resampling*) of 300 units from the *same* random sample is a statistical method named *bootstrapping* (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics).

Comment: Rather than the general definitions I am asking a specific question. How would the definitions fit to my example? Where would be the random experiment in my case? You mentioned resampling 300 units randomly is bootstrapping but does that mean it is not random experiment? What about the creation of the dataset by asking many people for the specified information is that a random experiment?

Comment: The *randomized* experiment is exctracting 3000 people randomly from a population. Resampling 300 units could be the first step in a statistical method named bootstrapping, it is not a *randomized* experiment.

Comment: That seems like a terrible definition. Whether or not something can be predicted depends on the knowledge/expertise of the experimenter.